# I am running my code in Google colab, it is showing this error. I had joined X_train and "y" column of y_train. I am unable to do the set up

Tags: pycaret

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht3Ph.png)

I am unable to do the setup in Pycaret.I had installed Pycaret library. It is showing error on class. I had joined two dataframe . The target variable is y column. It showing an error on class.